# Accessing app object from outside app context in Flask application

Tags: python, api, flask, key, config

I have set a decorator for functions of my routes to abort(401) if api-key is invalid (or not specified) inside headers of requests.

So I define this function in a dedicated file of my main module (named app) and it is imported inside all of my blueprints definition. But from this file, I have no access to app object to load the API key stored in config. I tried to use current_app, but I have an error telling me I cannot use it outside of the app context. I cannot import directly app object from app module either as it results with a circular importation.

If I declare the decorator inside `__init__.py` file, I will be faced with the same issue: I will not be able to import require_apikey function from app module as blueprint modules are already imported in app module for blueprint registration.

I assume there are some issues with my design. Could you point my flaws and help me fixing it ?

My project directory looks like this:

```
project/
 - run.py
 - app/
 - - __init__.py
 - - player.py
 - - require_apikey.py
```

And here is the content of these files:

```
# run.py
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
# app/__init__.py

from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    jsonify)

from app.db import db

from app.player import player

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("app.config.Config")
app.register_blueprint(player, url_prefix="/player/")

db.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

```
# app/player.py

from flask import (
    Blueprint,
    request,
    abort,
    jsonify)

from app import require_apikey

from app.models.player import Player

from app.db import db

player = Blueprint(__name__, __name__)

@player.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@require_apikey
def root():
    # Do some stuff
```

```
# app/require_apikey.py

from functools import wraps
from flask import (
    request,
    abort,
    current_app
)

API_KEY = current_app.config["SECRET_KEY"]

def require_apikey(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.headers.get("api-key") and request.headers.get("api-key") == API_KEY:
            return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401, "Invalid API key")
    return decorated_function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Setting up your app

Initializing your `app` in the `__init__` file of your project is very straightforward, but also very limited when the size of your project becomes bigger (and since you are using blueprints for your routes, I guess that the size of your project is big enough already).

The recommanded way of initializing your `app` in this case is to use an [App factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/), which is basically a function that creates and returns the `app` instance.

Here's a quick example of working arboresence (probably not the best one you will find, but that should do):

```py
# myapp/application/setup.py

from flask import Flask

from .application.extensions import db


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object("myapp.config.Config")

    # Initialize extensions
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        # Register Blueprints
        from myapp.player import player
        app.register_blueprint(player, url_prefix="/player/")
        return app
```

```py
# myapp/application/extensions.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# define global extensions in a separate file so that they can be imported from
# anywhere else in the code without creating circular imports
# the proper initialization is made within the `create_app` function 
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

```py
# myapp/application/app.py

from .setup import create_app

app = create_app()
```

```py
# myapp/__init__.py

from .application.app import app
```

```py
# run.py

from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

That's it for the hierarchy of your project. At this point, you have a `myapp/application/app.py` that initialized the `app` variable, and that you can import from anywhere you want without worrying about the import loops.

## Checking headers before calling the view function

With the arboresence I suggested, and considering you update your imports accordingly, your decorator should now be working as expected.
But what if I tell you Flask offers a way to do what you want, without implementing a decorator? This is where the [`before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) kicks in.
This is a special function you can write that will be called within the app-context before every single request on your application.

```py
from myapp.application.app import app


@app.before_request
def require_apikey():
    if request.headers.get("api-key") != API_KEY:
        abort(401, "Invalid API key")
```

Now the problem here is that this function will be called for every single endpoint you have defined, and maybe that's not what you want. But do not worry, you can also define a `before_request` function to attach to a specific blueprint.

```py
# myapp/my_blueprint.py
from myapp.tools import require_apikey

my_blueprint = Blueprint(...)
my_blueprint.before_request = require_apikey
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is way beyond my expectations.

I did not have time to answer earlier but I manage to get that I would fix my initial issue just by setting `API_KEY` *inside* my decorator function (which is inside a view function and so `current_app` is instantiated with proper app context).

Thank you for explaining the purpose of App Factory. I have already seen it but never understood why it is needed. Now it is clear. Although now I do not need it for this particular issue, I bet it will be useful later.

And `@before_request` is awesome.