# What settings am I missing in VS Code so that Flask print statement output shows up in terminal?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to get `print` statements to show up in my VS Code terminal. I'm running Flask 3.0 and Python 3.12 from VS Code 1.85.1.

Part A. I've read through a bunch of different posts and have assembled the following settings, mainly from [How do I debug Flask App in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171144/how-do-i-debug-flask-app-in-vs-code). My `launch.json`, `settings.json`, `app.py`, and `views.py` files are below. One print statement is in the `index()` function of the `views.py` file, and a few more scattered throughout the file. My app and HTML files run fine but I'm about to start making changes and want to know how to get `print` statements to show up in the VS Code terminal. I also checked my Debug Console just to be sure- nothing there.

Part B to this question is if I wanted to use `app.logger` in `views.py`, how would I do that? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405708/flask-doesnt-print-to-console

Thanks for pointers!

Windows environment variable: 
`FLASK_APP    .\app.py`

launch.json

```
{
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "app",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                // "run",
                // "--no-debugger",
                // "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "editor.defaultFoldingRangeProvider": "samuelcolvin.jinjahtml",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "formulahendry.code-runner"
}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import views

app =  Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'BAD_SECRET_KEY'
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/index', view_func=views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/page1', view_func=views.page_one_func)
app.add_url_rule('/page1_processed', view_func=views.page_one_add_input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = f"127.0.0.1:5000"
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

I tried setting `debug` and `use_reloader` to False with no difference.

views.py

```
def index():
    print('calling index...')
    return render_template('index.html.jinja')

def page_one_func():
    vars = {'exp_dict': exp_dict}
    return render_template('page1.html.jinja', vars=vars)

def page_one_add_input():
    vars = {'exp_dict': exp_dict}
    print(f"{type(request.args())}")
    # result = request.args.get('userinput')
    # vars['user_input']= request.form.get('userinput')
    return render_template('page1.html.jinja', vars=vars)
```

Comment: You could use logging with Flask's app.logger. Read about it here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/logging/

Comment: Then that goes to part B of my question. How do I use it if I instantiate the `app` and call the `views` module in `app.py`?

Comment: You can share the app object via flask.current_app function https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.current_app 
See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646448/accessing-app-object-from-outside-app-context-in-flask-application

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and follow up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Print statements will go to web server's logs by default.  You are probably using some variant of WSGI or IIS.  Unless you start the web server to display logs to the console within VSCode you aren't going to see your print statements.
It is also possible you are using IIS as a web server for Windows and the print statements would be in your server's logs.
Debugging code is different than seeing print statements in your VSCode.  This usually involves a debugger that can stop at breakpoints in your code and you can inspect the namespace as well as execute Python at that point to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

So I think it's working now. I was just having trouble piecing it all together. Thanks to Ted and sdawar. Here are the changes I made:

**SETUP**

For VS Code: launch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "internalConsole",    // <<<<<------
            //"console" : "integratedConsole", // commented out <<---
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py",
            "args": [
                // "run",
            ],
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            ["jinja" "javascript"]: true
        }
    ]
}
```

**SETUP:** The Flask app

A couple of the many references on setting up a logger in Flask: 
https://circleci.com/blog/application-logging-with-flask and 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152456/9915864

app.py:

```
from flask.logging import default_handler
from logging.config import dictConfig
from config_app import Configure
import views

## Simple logger: logging.basicConfig(filename='logging_output.log', mode='w+', level=logging.DEBUG)

## Or a very well-organized one per Saurabh
dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})


app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
```

**USAGE:** Finally, to call the app.logger in views.py or similar Blueprint type files, use `from flask import current_app`

views.py:

```
from flask import current_app

def index_func():
    current_app.logger.debug('\nCalling index_func\n')
    return render_template('index.html')
```